# iOS 10 barTintColor animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation, ios10

I've noticed a change in the way bar tint color animates in ios 10. I've created a sample project outlining the change: [Github: ios10BarTintDemo](https://github.com/johnryan/ios10BarTintDemo)

Basically on ios 9 the barTintColor animates smoothly using `[UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition]`

but on ios 10 the animations are much less smooth and when popping a view controller doesn't animate at all, I've tried adding `[self.navigationController.navigationBar layoutIfNeeded]` as mentioned in some similar answers but this doesn't seem to have any effect when pushing/popping controllers.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Not yet, still trying to figure it out and i'll update it here when I find a solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## UPDATE

I've tested in iOS 10.3 and I think the problem was fixed. And `transitionCordinator` is no need anymore. I think the animation is smooth. Please check my [project on github](https://github.com/k8mil/NavBarColorAnimation) or look at this code:

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        title = "A"
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "NEXT", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.showController))
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        setColors()
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    func showController() {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewControllerB(), animated: true)
    }

    private func setColors() {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    }
}




class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        title = "B"
        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        setColors()
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
        if parent == nil {
            navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
        }
        super.willMove(toParentViewController: parent)
    }


    private func setColors() {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .blue
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    }
}
```

============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================

To achieve this kind of animation you should use `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator` as [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrollertransitioncoordinator) say it is :

> An object that adopts the UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator protocol provides support for animations associated with a view controller transition.(...)

So every `UIViewController` has own `transitionController`. To get this you should call in the `UIViewControllerClass` :

`self.transitionCoordinator()`

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1619294-transitioncoordinator):

> Returns the active transition coordinator object.

So to get the result that you want you should implement `animateAlongsideTransition` method in viewController transitionCoordinatior. Animation works when you click `backButton` and swipe to back.

Example :

[image: navigation_bar_animation]

First Controller :

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        title = "A"
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "NEXT", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.showController))
        setColors()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        animate()
    }

    func showController() {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewControllerB(), animated: true)
    }

    private func animate() {
        guard let coordinator = self.transitionCoordinator else {
            return
        }

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: {
            [weak self] context in
            self?.setColors()
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    private func setColors() {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
    }
}
```

Second Controller:

```
class ViewControllerB : UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        title = "B"
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setColors()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        animate()
    }

    override func willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) { // tricky part in iOS 10
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red //previous color
        super.willMove(toParentViewController: parent)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .blue
    }

    private func animate() {
        guard let coordinator = self.transitionCoordinator else {
            return
        }
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: {
            [weak self] context in
            self?.setColors()
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    private func setColors(){
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .blue
    }

}
```

***UPDATE iOS 10***

In the iOS 10 the tricky part is to add the `willMoveTo(parentViewController parent: UIViewController?)` in the ***second*** ViewController. And set the navigationBar `tintColor` to the color value of ***previous*** controller. Also, in `viewDidAppear` method in ***second*** ViewControler set the `navigationBar.tintColor` to the color from ***second*** viewController.

***Check out my example [project on github](https://github.com/k8mil/NavBarColorAnimation)***

Comment: THANK YOU! didn't think to use the previous color in will move to parent

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I was missing the willMoveToParent override which caused a weird color jump when hitting the back button.

Comment: This looks amazing. One question though, how can I know what I can animate with this technique? It works like a charm with the barTintColor, but I can't seem to be able to do the same with changing the backgroundColor of a subview I added to the UINavigationBar. I even took your github project and I worked there, but no luck...

Comment: `if navigationBar.isTranslucent == false` then there's a delay in changing color and this doesn't work

Comment: @Chlebta Did you fix this issue ?

Comment: @Chlebta Checkout my upaded answer. I think the animation is smooth without using `transitionCoordiator` and I also set the `isTranslucent` to false.

Answer (score 5):

You can fix this popping issue by adding something similar to this, running it in viewWillDisappear won't work for some reason in iOS10

```
override func willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
    super.willMove(toParentViewController: parent)
}
```

Comment: I tried adding this to the sample project and it didn't seem to help, it works for you?